# How do you get a list of all developers and apps for an API in Apigee?

Tags: apigee

Say you have exposed an API Product in Apigee. You would like to get a list of all the developers and their apps that have registered for the API Product.

There is a call to return those, documented here:

```
http://apigee.com/docs/api/get-list-keys-apps-developers-or-companies-api-product
```

But the IDs it returns appear to be useless. If you try developers, for instance:

```
https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/YOUR-ORG/apiproducts/YOUR-PRODUCT?query=list&entity=developers
```

you get back a list of IDs. But to find which developer a given ID relates to is impossible, as the call to get a developer:

```
http://apigee.com/docs/api/get-developer
```

only accepts an email address.

How can I get a list of all the developers and their apps registered for a given API product?

Answer (score 1):

The Apps a developer has is nested in each developer:

```
   https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{your org}/developers
```

will return a list of developers like this:

```
   ["email@domain.com", "email2@domain2.com"]
```

Then you have to loop through each developer to get a list of their apps:

```
   https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{your org}/developers/tesla@weathersample.com
```

Which gives you a bunch of meta data including apps:

```
{
  "apps" : [ "weather" ],
  "companies" : [ ],
  "email" : "tesla@weathersample.com",
  "developerId" : "Hk5mmLw9kKIM95qF",
  "firstName" : "Nikolai",
  "lastName" : "Tesla",
  "userName" : "Nikolai",
  "organizationName" : "jokeindex",
  "status" : "active",
  "attributes" : [ ],
  "createdAt" : 1357858239543,
  "createdBy" : "noreply_admin@apigee.com",
  "lastModifiedAt" : 1357858239543,
  "lastModifiedBy" : "noreply_admin@apigee.com"
}
```

Finally, if you look at each app you can see the products associated with that developer app:

```
   https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{your org}/developers/tesla@weathersample.com/apps/weather
```

Gets you this detail:

```
{
  "accessType" : "read",
  "appFamily" : "default",
  "appId" : "030fdcea-cf97-40b1-96df-12084aea513c",
  "attributes" : [ {
    "name" : "Developer",
    "value" : "tesla@weathersample.com"
  }, {
    "name" : "DisplayName",
    "value" : "Weather"
  }, {
    "name" : "Notes",
    "value" : "not yet"
  }, {
    "name" : "lastModifier",
    "value" : ""
  } ],
  "callbackUrl" : "http://example.com/callback",
  "createdAt" : 1363578857830,
  "createdBy" : "adminui@apigee.com",
  "credentials" : [ {
    "apiProducts" : [ {
      "apiproduct" : "weather",
      "status" : "approved"
    } ],
    "attributes" : [ ],
    "consumerKey" : "{key}",
    "consumerSecret" : "{key}",
    "expiresAt" : -1,
    "scopes" : [ ],
    "status" : "approved"
  } ],
  "developerId" : "Hk5mmLw9kKIM95qF",
  "lastModifiedAt" : 1386042817268,
  "lastModifiedBy" : "michael.bissell@apigee.com",
  "name" : "weather",
  "scopes" : [ ],
  "status" : "approved"
}
```

Take a look at the Org Snapshot Tool on git if you want to interrogate the entire org with one script:

https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/tools

This will interrogate every developer and every app and put it into a nice tree structure in your file system for future reference.